# How to calculate the luminous wavelength of $\mathrm{LaB}_6$ at a specific temperature?

Tags: optics, material-science, particle-accelerators

I have a problem. I want to know the wavelength of light emitted by the cathode made by LaB<sub>6</sub> at 1700℃. But I did a lot of research and didn't find any message about it. It's not very accurate if using blackbody radiation to estimate. Where can I find the wavelength of light emitted by LaB<sub>6</sub> with temperature change? Or is there any formula to calculate it?

PS: The reason why I do this is that the cathode made by LaB<sub>6</sub> will emit strong light at high temperature (around 1700℃), which will conduct round hole diffraction on the instrument behind and produce a bright Airy disk on the target. I want to calculate the size and intensity of the Airy disk, so I need to know the wavelength of light.
Thanks!

Comment: At that temperature, it will be a good approximation of a blackbody radiator. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation or http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/bbcon.html#c1

Answer (score 0):

This is not so simple.

at 1700 deg C, the peak wavelength is at 1.5 microns, and continuous through the visible spectrum monotonically decreasing sharply from red to blue.   I doubt you will see a classic Airy disk consisting of a central spot and concentric rings.  The size of the hole also plays a role, as does the size of the cathode and the distance from the cathode to the hole.

But since the radiation is predominantly red, and the eye is most sensitive at around 550 nm, a reasonable choice for a characteristic wavelength is 650 nm.  A calculation can be done to find the peak wavelength of the perceived spectrum, but given the continuous spectrum, I don't believe it would help more than this hand-waving argument.